How to Properly Load Zest Script for Authentication in OWASP ZAP API Scan using GitLab CI/CD Pipeline?
I am trying to trigger security tests using a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. The pipeline uses a Docker runner to launch an OWASP ZAP container on the server. The tests involve an API scan, but I encounter the same issue with a full scan as well.
I have a context file where I define authentication using a Zest script, and I also attach the script file. The problem is that I am not sure where exactly I should place the Zest script for it to be correctly located and loaded by ZAP. When I run the scan with a context file that uses something like "auto authentication," the scan works fine. However, if the context specifies a Zest script for authentication, I get an error indicating that the script cannot be found at the specified location.
Error from the logs:
2024-10-22 11:38:19,938 http://localhost:38280 "GET http://zap/JSON/context/action/importContext/?contextFile=%2Fzap%2Fwrk%2FContext.context HTTP/1.1" 500 52
2024-10-22 11:38:19,939 Failed to load context file /zap/wrk/Context.context : internal_error
I couldn't gather any better information from either the GitLab or ZAP Docker logs.
Relevant part of the GitLab YAML code:
yaml
- cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/script.zst /zap/scripts/

cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/script.zst /zap/scripts/scripts/authentication/

cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Context.context /zap/wrk/

echo "Starting zap-api-scan.py script with API scan..."

zap-api-scan.py -t $API_SPEC_URL -f openapi -n Context.context -z "  -config api.disablesslverification=true -config log.level=DEBUG -config view.loglevel.debug=true" -x zap-api-report.xml -d || true


Does anyone know the correct directory or path where the Zest script should be stored so that OWASP ZAP can locate and load it correctly during the scan? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried copying the Zest script to various directories within the ZAP container, including:
/zap/scripts/
/zap/scripts/scripts/authentication/

In my GitLab CI/CD pipeline, I also tried specifying different paths for the Zest script within the context file and confirmed the paths matched in the container. However, the issue persists with the context loading failing with an internal error.
I expected ZAP to successfully locate and load the Zest script for authentication based on the paths specified in the context file. When using simpler forms of authentication defined directly in the context, such as "auto authentication," the scan runs without any issues. Therefore, I assume the issue is related to the way the Zest script is being referenced or the location where it needs to be stored.
